# Entity Class is a non Entity?

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, eclipselink

I got the following Error:

**[class model.VerkaufterArtikel] uses a non-entity [class model.Verkauf] as target entity in the relationship attribute [field verkauf].**

But the class is listed in the persistence.xml. And I tried also to not exlude unlisted classes.

I'm using EclipseLink as JPA Implementation.

I tried to exlude the relation but then I was not able to persist Verkauf. The other classes are working correctly.

The situation is: I have a sale(Verkauf) wich contains sold items(VerkaufteArtikel).

model.Verkauf:

```java
package model;


@Entity
@Table(name = "verkauf")
@NamedQuery(name = "Verkauf.findAll", query = "SELECT v FROM Verkauf v")
public class Verkauf implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private int verkID;



    private int gegeben;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="verkauf")
    private List<VerkaufterArtikel> verkaufArtikels = new ArrayList<VerkaufterArtikel>();
```

model.VerkaufterArtikel:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="verkauf_artikel")
@NamedQuery(name="VerkaufArtikel.findAll", query="SELECT v FROM VerkaufterArtikel v")
public class VerkaufterArtikel implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private int id;

    private float anz;

    private int artID;

    private int preispro;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="verkaufID")
    private Verkauf verkauf;
```

My persistence XML:

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="dbm" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <!-- <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>-->
        <class>model.Artikel</class>
        <class>model.ArtikelInWarenkorb</class>
        <class>model.VerkaufterArtikel</class>
        <class>model.Verkaeufer</class>
        <class>model.Verkauf</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mdb" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="eclipselink.allow-zero-id" value="true" />
        </properties>


    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And the Tables:

```java
CREATE TABLE `verkauf_artikel` (
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`verkaufID` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`artID` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`anz` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`preispro` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),

CREATE TABLE `verkauf` (


id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `verkID` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `zeit` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `gegeben` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the reason for this error.

I had a getSum() method at the bottom of the class. I removed the method and everything is working fine now!

```
public int getSum() {

    return (int) getVerkaufArtikels()
            .stream()
            .mapToDouble(acc -> ((double) acc.getPreispro() * acc.getAnz()))
            .sum();
}
```

Comment: what was that method doing? can you add it also? Why was it triggering the given issue?

Comment: I added the Method to the answer. I don't know what the reason is. I think entitys should contain only their fields and the getters and setters.

Answer (score 0):

I think your @ManyToOneMapping is not correct, it should look like this:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="verkID")
private Verkauf verkauf;
```

Comment: I chose verkaufID according to http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToOne#Example_of_a_ManyToOne_relationship_database

I also tried your suggestion. Same error. My situation is like the one in the first example.

Comment: Sorry, just came from vacation, I need some time to warm up :-) It seems that VerkaufArtikel is mapped into Verkauf by verkID, not verkaufID. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I updatet the Question with the Table definitions. I'm not sure verkID is the solution

Comment: You are correct, I was misguided because you have verkID field in table Verkauf. Everything seems OK with your configuration. Could you post more information about application server you are using? Are you using NetBeans with embedded Glassfish? If this is the case, you might try to delete cache folder ~/.netbeans/7.0/var/cache.

Comment: I'm not using an application server. I tried to delete all caches, even did a fresh checkout into a new workspace... still the same problem